# How to read events stored in Axon Event Store?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, axon, axon-framework

I am struggling to understand how to connect to a default Axon Event Store and see what events are stored there? Is there a way to preview it somehow?

How do I **replay** stored events to re-create a particular state of a stored Entity? I am trying to find an example, tutorial, or a video lesson on the internet and cannot find anything ...
How do I make a snapshot and then retrieve it? Cannot find any online example on how to do it...
Can someone advise or share a link to a discussion here on StackOverflow if this has been asked before?

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

I feel there's a threefold of questions here.
Firstly the title, secondly if there are any tutorials and thirdly how to recreate entities. It would've been best to create separate questions out of this for clarity, but I'll answer them regardless.

### 1. Read Events Stored in Axon's Event Store

If you are using Axon Server, reading events is as simple as browsing to Axon Server's dashboard. From there you can click the `Search` button which opens up the search pan allowing you to check all the events which have been stored. There's a fleshed-out Query Language present there, which is explained in detail here -> https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/appendices/query-reference.

If the Axon Server UI doesn't suit your needs, the easiest approach would be to use `curl`. To get an idea what operation you can do, you can check out Axon Server's swagger page (at http:[server]:[port]/swagger-ui.html).

If you are not using Axon Server than your events are either stored in an RDBMS or MongoDb. If you want to know how to read from either, I would recommend to either read the documentation of the used RDBMS instance or MongoDb on how to query a table.

### 2. Axon Tutorial Material

I'd assume simply googling for "axon coding example" *should* give you plenty of information, but let me provide you some just in this answer:

- [AxonIQ Academy](https://academy.axoniq.io/)
- [Axon Reference Guide](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/)
- [Axon Intro Video Series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4O1nDpoa5KQkkApGXjKi3rzUW3II5pjm)
- [Axon Hotel Demo](https://github.com/AxonIQ/hotel-demo)
- [Baeldung's Axon Article](https://www.baeldung.com/axon-cqrs-event-sourcing)
- [Axon's Intro Training](https://axoniq.io/event-overview/intro-to-event-driven-microservices-using-ddd-cqrs--event-sourcing-feb-2021)
- [Domain Driven Design](https://axoniq.io/resources/domain-driven-design)
- [Command Query Responsibility Segregation](https://axoniq.io/resources/cqrs)
- [Event Sourcing](https://axoniq.io/resources/event-sourcing)

### 3. Recreating Models in Axon

Now, when it comes to reading events, in virtually all scenarios you will *never* have to do this manually with Axon Framework.
You simply mark a method as being capable of handling events with the `@EventHandler` annotation, and the framework will find the handler automatically and register it to the `EventBus`/`EventStore`.

For recreation of entities, the same applies, but there's an added layer. As Axon promotes usages of CQRS, you will have distinct models in place. The Command Model is what Axon supports through the Aggregate specifics to be found [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/axon-framework-commands/modeling/aggregate). Recreating the aggregate from its own events is completely done for you by the framework every time the aggregate is loaded from the aggregate's `Repository`. This is the case as Axon implements an `EventSourcingRepository` which simply follows the paradigm of recreating the entity **every time**.

If the entity you want to recreate is part of the Query Model, you will have to tell the component in charge of providing the events to your `@EventHandler`s to start from scratch (thus again *no need for you* to read events yourself). The technical aspect in Axon which trails the `EventStore` is called the `EventProcessor`. If you want an `EventProcessor` which can replay those events to recreate your entities, you will have to use the `TrackingEventProcessor` (TEP). It is the TEP which exposes a `resetTokens()` operation which essentially changes the Event Processor's point in the event stream to a point in the past; thus allowing you to recreate your entities. The documentation on this can be found [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-processors#replaying-events).

### 4. Invoking reset on a TrackingEventProcessor

If you want to recreate a Query Model, either because its format has changed or simply because you have a new model, you would require a reset of the `TrackingToken(s)` of the `TrackingEventProcessor` (TEP). Mind you, this requires you to use the TEP as the processor for an Event Handling Component (the class containing `@EventHandler` annotated methods) updating the model you want to recreate. Only the TEP provides the option to be reset, as it is the sole Event Processor using `TrackingTokens` to track its progress through the event stream. By adjusting its position on that stream, you effectively invoke a reset.

If you want to reset a TEP, you will first need to know the name of the processor. By default, this would be the package name of the Event Handling Components (EHC). It is however recommended to use the `@ProcessingGroup` annotation on the EHC to give distinct names to your processing groups, and thus the event processor. It helps with reasoning about the group, but also gives an easier handle to invoke resets through.

With the name in hand, we are all set to find the TEP within Axon's configuration. For this, you can best use the `EventProcessingConfiguration`, as it exposes an `eventProcessor(String, Class<T>)` method which returns an `Optional<EventProcessor>` for you. With this optional in hand, you can start the reset operation.
Prior to resetting a TEP, you must make sure **no single TEP instance is handling events**. This means you will have to shut down the TEP first, with the `TrackingEventProcessor#shutDown` method. After this, the reset can be invoked, which effectively adjusts the `TrackingToken(s)` of the TEP to the new position. After this, your TEP can be started up again.

In code, this would like as follows:

```java
public void resetTrackingProcessor(EventProcessingConfiguration config, String processorName) {
    config.eventProcessor(processorName, TrackingEventProcessor.class)
          .ifPresent(tep -> {
              tep.shutDown();
              tep.resetTokens();
              tep.start();
          });
}
```

Note that the above would work completely fine in a single node system, as then the `shutdown` operation while shut down the only TEP present. If you have distributed your application into several instances, however, then *you* will need to figure out a way to shut down all those instances prior to invoking the reset on one of them. Simply put, you need a central component, outside of the scope of the given application, which knows about all existing TEP out there. It is perfectly doable to create this yourself (I've done this in the past), but I would nowadays recommend you to safe you the hassle by using Axon Server.

Axon Server acts as the middle man, no just for event storage and message distribution, but also as a place to monitor your system. Thus, also your Event Processors, with the addition of exposing the shut down, start, release token, split and merge operations.

Comment: thank you. This is very helpful . When I said I cannot find any tutorials, I meant I cannot find anything on how to replay events to re-create a particular state of an Entity. Can you share a link to a guide or tutorial that you know that will explain this?    For example how to recreate an Order entity when it had a field status set to "failed" and the orderId field set to "abc"?

Comment: Just to be completely sure, when you are talking about the replay of an `Order` entity, you are talking about a Query Model `Order` which is updated by `@EventHandler` annotated methods and stored (into for example an RDBMS)?

Comment: Yes. To my knowledge, the Write DB contains a final state of the Order but it is the Event Store that contains a history of all the events that happened to an Order. Event Sourcing allows us to replay the events from an Event Store to re-create an Order and get its state at a particular point. So I am trying to find a guide on how to actually to it. I've also read that in those cases when an object state is updated often and there too many events in the Events Store, Axon allows to create snapshots, and Replay can be done using snapshots. Can't find a guide explaining it in details.

Comment: I am afraid you are making a conceptual mismatch between the two types of models you have when doing CQRS. The Command Model is what's being event sourced and which supports snapshots. In Axon, this is the Aggregate. The Command Model is however NOT used for answers queries to users. The Query Model simply tails the event stream and updates models dedicated to answering the questions your applications have. The benefit of this segregation is that _you_ can choose whatever datasource you use for the model.

Comment: Axon's support on Query Models however does not extend automatic event sourcing or snapshots. What it does support, is replaying at your own convenience, so that you can recreate the models if they have changed. I have specified all of this already in point 3 of my answer.

This means, that for the Command Model, you don't have to do anything to allow replays. Axon does this. On the Query Model, you _do_ need to invoke this yourself.

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide additional links with information. There is no "this is how to replay" tutorial out there though. The documentation should, however, be sufficient to figure this out too.

Comment: thank you. No, I was not planning to use the Command API to answer queries or replay events. I know it is a responsibility of a Query API to respond to queries. I cannot figure out how to replay events from the events store in the Query API. It is not clear from the documentation how to do it. There is no code example at all  and this is why I have published this question. The "Event sourcing" section on the page you have shared, has a link but this link is broken. It results in Page Not Found. Steven, do you know any other documentation page that might have some code snippets?

Comment: I went through your answer one more time and found something in the event processors section here https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-processors#replaying-events. Will try to get it working...

Comment: I went the stretch to give you exactly what you were looking for. I held off on this, as the question felt rather ambiguous to me. Luckily, this comment section clarified your intent sufficiently at this stage. Again, let me know if this helps you out @interested-dev

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!
I have seen using the event store as a history log to show the changes on an aggregate during time on the frontend client. This was done manually. I don't think it should be done in this way because it's like reading from a "write model". I would create a dedicated Query Model for the history that store all the changes by listening to the events. Am I right or it's also good practice to read from the events store directly. Thanks.

Comment: In most scenarios, I would completely agree with that stance @Pietro, but it does depend. CQRS allows you to optimize consciously how you deal with your Command Model, but also with your Query Model. In most cases, optimizing for speeds is the most reasonable step to take. Thus, storing and updating the Query Model by tailing the event stream instead of recreating it every time is from hat perspective most reasonable. If you, however, have a requirement that you need to safe on storage space, then recreating it might be a better fit.

Comment: So, in short, it depends. :-)

Comment: Hi! Is there a way to query Events stored in Axon in any other way which is not the UI? Like their REST API or gRPC API? I am looking for something like "Get events by timestamp" or "Get events by global index". I could only find a way to get events by Aggregate Identifier but this does not fit my usecase as I cannot use Aggregate ID.

Comment: Sure! You can check out the REST API on the Swagger page and use `curl` instead if you like. I've updated my answer to reflect that in the first part.